# Struts 1 Date Format Tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

Is there any tag in Struts1 tag library which can format a `java.util.Date` object?

In Struts 2, I can use the `s:date` tag, but I can't find the Struts 1 equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing like that appears in the [Sruts tag reference](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html). You can however use the [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`fmt:formatDate`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) tag for this. JSTL and Struts1 almost go hand in hand.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
...
<p><fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
<p><fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" type="date" dateStyle="long" />
```

Which should print like:

```
2010-06-18
June 18, 2010
```

It uses the [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) under the hoods. Its Javadoc is more descriptive about the available patterns and styles.

Answer (score 7):

Can't you use format attribute? Something like:

```
bean:write name=xxxx  format="MMMM-dd-yyyy"
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for the use of `format="MM-dd-yyyy"` as an attribute for `bean:write` tag.